# Haskell Boomerang Compilation Error

Tags: haskell, web-routes-boomerang

So I thought I'd have some fun parsing some AIS data with Boomerang, and I'm stumbling at the first hurdle. The compilation errors are baffling. Seeing as I've parse similar things in Boomerang before I'm stuck trying to solve this.

The library is simple. I define some basic types and their parser/grammar:

```
import           Control.Category      (id, (.))
import           Control.Monad         (forever)
import           Prelude               hiding (id, (.))
import           System.IO             (hFlush, stdout)
import           Text.Boomerang
import           Text.Boomerang.String
import           Text.Boomerang.TH

data MessageType = AIVDM | AIVDO deriving (Enum, Eq, Show)

data AIS = AIS {
              msgType :: MessageType
          } deriving (Eq, Show)

$(makeBoomerangs ''MessageType)
$(makeBoomerangs ''AIS)

messageTypeP :: StringBoomerang () (MessageType :- ())
messageTypeP = rAIVDM . "!AIVDM" <> rAIVDO . "!AIVDO"

aisP :: StringBoomerang () (AIS :- ())
aisP = rAIS . messageTypeP . lit ","
```

I now wish to support the sentence count value, which comes after the message type; I add an `Int` to `AIS`:

```
data AIS = AIS {
              msgType :: MessageType, sCount :: Int
          } deriving (Eq, Show)
```

and change the parser/printer:

```
aisP :: StringBoomerang () (AIS :- ())
aisP = rAIS . messageTypeP . lit "," . int
```

but it fails to compile:

```
• Couldn't match type ‘()’ with ‘Int :- ()’
  Expected type: Boomerang
                   StringError String () (MessageType :- (Int :- ()))
    Actual type: Boomerang StringError String () (MessageType :- ())
• In the second argument of ‘(.)’, namely
    ‘messageTypeP . lit "," . int’
  In the expression: rAIS . messageTypeP . lit "," . int
  In an equation for ‘aisP’:
      aisP = rAIS . messageTypeP . lit "," . int
```

Ouch. Help, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boomerangs should be polymorphic.

```
messageTypeP :: StringBoomerang r (MessageType :- r)

aisP :: StringBoomerang r (AIS :- r)
```

The interpretation is that `r` is a stack of types, and boomerangs pop/push types from/into it. Setting `r` to `()` forces the input stack to be empty, which hurts the reusability of these boomerangs.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you :)